# ExceptionUtil is missed in Hibernate4

Tags: hibernate, migration

We are migrating our code from Hibernate3.1 to Hibernate 4.0. But some of the classes which is in Hibernate3.1 is not available in Hibernate4.0.

for e.g., ExceptionUtil.class is not available in Hibernate4.0

Could you please suggest the alternative code for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Class [ExceptionUtils](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils.java) in [org.apache.commons.lang.exception](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/exception/ExceptionUtils.java) package.
You need to download [commons-lang-2.6.jar](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/) and add to class path.

I visited below mentioned links but I could not find the class `ExceptionUtils`

- [hibernate 4.1 deprecated-list of class](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/javadocs/deprecated-list.html#class)
- [hibernate 3.3 API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/)